# Get a language's ISO identifier from its name

Tags: ios, locale, nslocale

I know I can get the device's current Locale easily but in my case, the user chooses the language from a UIPickerView. Each language is a string in a array typed exactly the same way the phone has it in the settings for setting the device language.

Is it possible to get the language abbreviation from a string like @"English" or @"Arabic"?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`NSLocale`'s [`+canonicalLocaleIdentifierFromString:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSLocale_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/NSLocale/canonicalLocaleIdentifierFromString%3a) does this translation.

Comment: Thanks but the only issue is Chinese (simplified or traditional), it doesn't seem to get that one :/

Comment: They are identified with "Simplified Chinese" and "Traditional Chinese". Refer to ICU's list of [Language Display Names](http://demo.icu-project.org/icu-bin/locexp?_=en&SHOWLanguages=1#Languages) for a complete list.